Python requests/urllib not returning status 200 when in production
I am struggling to request these images below:
Image 1: 'https://venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br/fotos/F878770754273521.jpg'
Image 2: 'https://venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br/fotos/F000001001212121.jpg'

I have tested this code with other websites and work fine, the problem is just with this specific website 'https://venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br/'.

Testing the code locally for the website above, it works fine, however when I deploy to Heroku does not work and on Heroku log HTTP error: 403 - Forbidden.

I have testes with using the library SSL verification and without it, both methods does not work.

I have also tried to use request library instead of urllib.


Any idea why this work locally and not in production? How can I by pass the blockage? I guess Heorku IP range is blocked by this website.. if so, there is a way to bypass this?
@app.route('/teste', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def teste():
    import ssl
    # Define the headers as specified
    headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Host': 'venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; filibot/1.0; +https://filibot.com/)',
        'X-Request-Id': 'httpdev.b2e27aba-d204-417a-95fa-d8a9dadb88f5',
        'Referer': 'https://http.app/'
    }

# Create a request object with the headers
url = 'https://venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br/fotos/F000001001212121.jpg'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

# Create an SSL context to disable SSL verification (for debugging purposes)
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
status = 0

# Open the URL with the custom request and SSL context
try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=context) as response:
        # Print the response status code
        print('Response Status Code:', response.getcode())
        status = response.getcode()
        # Get the response headers
        response_headers = response.getheaders()
        for header in response_headers:
            print(f'{header[0]}: {header[1]}')

        # Read and print a portion of the content
        content = response.read()
        print('Content Length:', len(content))

except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(f"HTTP error: {e.code} - {e.reason}")

except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print(f"URL error: {e.reason}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

status = str(status)
return status


I have tested this code with other websites and work fine, the problem is just with this specific website 'https://venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br/'.

Testing the code locally for the website above, it works fine, however when I deploy to Heroku does not work and on Heroku log HTTP error: 403 - Forbidden.

I have testes with using the library SSL verification and without it, both methods does not work.


My target is to get Response Status Code: 200 in production.

If venda-imoveis.caixa.gov.br is blocking by IP address, you might consider trying a proxy

For context, "Caixa" is a large Brazilian bank. They don't seem to be blocking foreigner IPs, but it's not surprising that they'd block cloud IPs.
